# Is there any function which can change order number in DB & admin in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Order Number not found in database after adding prefix in the order id

I have used below code and its working fine only for admin. But when i ship that order i got the error order number not found.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'CK-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Admin and emails showing Order number with prefix like my order number is 101
than it will save in database with order id 101 but its shows on front end CK-101. But when i ship that order, Order id CK-101 is not found in database and send me error.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try any plugin

Comment: Can you please suggest me plugin name

Answer (score 0):

Your function just adds the prefix in admin, frontend, emails etc but not in the database. Due to that you are getting the error.

Use the below functions to save it to database as well

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_sequential_order_number', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'set_sequential_order_number', 10, 2 );

function set_sequential_order_number( $post_id, $post ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( 'shop_order' === $post->post_type && 'auto-draft' !== $post->post_status ) {

        $order        = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        $order_number = self::get_order_meta( $order, '_order_number' );

        if ( '' === $order_number ) {

            // attempt the query up to 3 times for a much higher success rate if it fails (due to Deadlock)
            $success = false;

            for ( $i = 0; $i < 3 && ! $success; $i++ ) {

                // this seems to me like the safest way to avoid order number clashes
                $query = $wpdb->prepare( "
                    INSERT INTO {$wpdb->postmeta} (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
                    SELECT %d, '_order_number', IF( MAX( CAST( meta_value as UNSIGNED ) ) IS NULL, 1, MAX( CAST( meta_value as UNSIGNED ) ) + 1 )
                        FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
                        WHERE meta_key='_order_number'",
                    $post_id );

                $success = $wpdb->query( $query );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or use the below plugin which includes all the functions including the one you are already using

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/

Hope it helps.